# Cannot install VLC Media Player

Tags: vlc

I am having problems with:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but
    2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
         Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: What command did you used to install VLC?

Comment: First can you try installing from a terminal - sudo apt-get install vlc - This should work, you should not need these dependencies, did you get it from a website ?

Answer (score 0):

Type `software-properties-gtk` in terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as root and make sure that the restricted and universe repositories are enabled.

Then try this,

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then try to install vlc again

```
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```